# SQL Server select runs in 1 second from command line but times out at 30 seconds from website

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, iis, laravel

I am running Laravel 4 on IIS with SQL Server as the database. I am using eloquent in Laravel to query the database. All queries but one are running very quickly using this method. The one query that isn't running times out after 30 seconds. When I grab the raw SQL from the SQL Profiler and run it from the command line it completes in 1 second. I'm trying to figure out why there is such a time difference between running the SQL from the web application and running it from the command line (SQL Server Management Studio). We have cleared the cache before running each query and the result is the same.

My Laravel Eloquent code (times out):

```
$checks = SQLServerHostLastCheck::where('organization_id', '=', Session::get('currentIssueTrakOrganizationID'))
  ->where('hostname', '=', $hostname)
  ->orderBy('check_level')
  ->orderBy('instance_name')
  ->orderBy('check_description')
  ->get();
```

I also tried this way (times out):

```
$checks = DB::table('sql_server_host_last_check_all_v')
  ->where('organization_id', '=', Session::get('currentIssueTrakOrganizationID'))
  ->where('hostname', '=', $hostname)
  ->get();
```

This is the raw SQL from the SQL Profiler (completes in 1 second):

```
select * from [sql_server_host_last_check_all_v] where [organization_id] = 1 and [hostname] = 'PSMWISSUE01' order by [check_level] asc, [instance_name] asc, [check_description] asc;
```

This query returns 66 rows and there are a total of 15 columns. There is only a small amount of data in each of the fields.

Comment: Your result is probably cached, so when you run it the second time it comes up very quickly.  Try with different values and see if it takes longer.

Comment: @Christopher Morrissey Even when I change the value the command line query completes in 1 second. We have also cleared the cache between running queries and the results are the same.

Comment: Why are you pulling back all columns?   Is there any large data (such as varchar(max) or varbinary) in your table?  It could take a while to send large data such as that down the network connection

Comment: @Sparky Only 66 rows are returned for this query and the largest column is varchar(8000) but it isn't even close to full for any of the records. There are also only 15 columns and returning all columns is how Laravel typically works.

Comment: What is this: sql_server_host_last_check_all_v? What query plan is generated for your query?

Comment: I solved this by creating a stored procedure instead of a view for the complex SQL query / joins that were building the view. The results are now returned in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a stored procedure instead of a view for the complex SQL query / joins that were building the view. The results are now returned in no time.